# Фон и phone

Tags: этимология

Корень -фон (от латинского phone) имеет смысл "звук". А откуда взялось слово фон как "задний план", тоже явно заимствованное? Случайно ли совпадение звучания?

Comment: > Корень -фон (от латинского phone)

У меня есть подозрение, что это не латинский корень. И бух ты... Пожалуйста: [φωνή][1]. Вполне себе греческий корень.

[1]:http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%86%CF%89%CE%BD%CE%AE#Ancient_Greek

Comment: Итого. Действительно, получилось так, что совпадение звучания случайное.

Comment: Точно, греческий! Как это я сразу не догадалась! Наверное, пора спать ложиться, голова уже не соображает )) Спокойной ночи!

Comment: Спокойной!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> А откуда взялось слово фон как "задний
> план", тоже явно заимствованное?

У Фасмера: Через нем. Fond "фон, задний план" из франц. Fond "основание, дно" от лат. fundus.

Comment: Да, я тоже посмотрела там. Значит, сходство звучания случайное? Или конечное  -d потерялось не случайно?  

Впрочем, я прослушала (через гугл-переводчик) оба варианта, вроде d не звучит даже в немецком. А во французском вообще слышно практически одно придыхание.  Но, может, это недостатки программы...

Comment: Так в немецком же Fond произносится как "фон", причем конечное "н" сильно смазано.

Comment: Значит, гугл-переводчик не врет! Это приятно!  
Кстати, слово "фонд" в русском языке от того же корня. Причем у Фасмера говорится, что даже через те же языки! (ладно бы еще через латынь!)  Почему же тут все буквы выговариваются?

Comment: <Кстати, слово "фонд" в русском языке от того же корня.>
Почему того же? 
Фон - слово с непроизводной основой, фонд - то же самое. То есть корни разные.
<Почему же тут все буквы выговариваются?> Потому что s на конце: Fonds ) (кстати, они не все выговариваются)

Comment: извините, я хотела сказать "того же происхождения", от fond.  

А что, fonds - это другое слово? Или просто форма от fond? К сожалению, я знаю только английский...

Comment: Не формы. Der Fond — фон, основа, der Fonds — запас, кладезь.

Comment: А какие из них связаны с fundus (лат)

Comment: Видимо, фон, раз Фасмер так говорит )

Comment: *нем.* [Fonds][1] - от *франц.* [fond][2]. А оно уже от *лат.* [fundus][3]
Русское же [фонд][4] предлагают образовывать от франц. [fonds][5]. А французы, ох, как любят глотать последнюю буквы.

[1]:http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fonds
[2]:http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fond#French
[3]:http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fundus#Latin
[4]:http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4#Russian
[5]:http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fonds#French

Comment: >Не формы. Der Fond — фон, основа, der Fonds — запас, кладезь.
Кстати, тоже можно опровергнуть. [der Fond][1]: Plural: Fonds

[1]:http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Fond

Answer (score 0):

Фон  [фр. fond< лат. fundus дно, основание] 1) в живописи, рисунке, скульптурном рельефе, орнаменте--та  часть  поверхности, на  которой  выделяются, вырисовываются  лавные  элементы  композиции, главные  предметы  изображения.

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос не совсем об этом.